# Formatting unknown output in a table in Python

Tags: python, output

Help! I'm a Python beginner given the assignment of displaying the Collatz Sequence from a user-inputted integer, and displaying the contents in columns and rows. As you may know, the results could be 10 numbers, 30, or 100. I'm supposed to use '\t'. I've tried many variations, but at best, only get a single column. e.g.

```
def sequence(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return number // 2    
    else:
        result = number * 3 + 1
        return result


n = int(input('Enter any positive integer to see Collatz Sequence:\n'))
while sequence != 1:
    n = sequence(int(n))
    print('%s\t' % n)
    if n == 1:
        print('\nThank you! The number 1 is the end of the Collatz Sequence')
        break
```

Which yields a single vertical column, rather than the results being displayed horizontally. Ideally, I'd like to display 10 results left to right, and then go to another line. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe:

```
def get_collatz(n):
    return [n // 2, n * 3 + 1][n % 2]

while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a positive integer: ")
    try:
        n = int(user_input)
        assert n > 1
    except (ValueError, AssertionError):
        continue
    else:
        break

sequence = [n]
while True:
    last_item = sequence[-1]
    if last_item == 1:
        break
    sequence.append(get_collatz(last_item))

print(*sequence, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
Enter a positive integer: 12
12  6   3   10  5   16  8   4   2   1
>>>
```

*EDIT* Trying to keep it similar to your code:

I would change your `sequence` function to something like this:

```
def get_collatz(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n // 2
    return n * 3 + 1
```

I called it `get_collatz` because I think that is more descriptive than `sequence`, it's still not a great name though - if you wanted to be super explicit maybe `get_collatz_at_n` or something.

Notice, I took the else branch out entirely, since it's not required. If `n % 2 == 0`, then we return from the function, so either you return in the body of the `if` or you return one line below - no `else` necessary.

For the rest, maybe:

```
last_number = int(input("Enter a positive integer: "))
while last_number != 1:
    print(last_number, end="\t")
    last_number = get_collatz(last_number)
```

In Python, `print` has an optional keyword parameter named `end`, which by default is `\n`. It signifies which character should be printed at the very end of a print-statement. By simply changing it to `\t`, you can print all elements of the sequence on one line, separated by tabs (since each number in the sequence invokes a separate print-statement).

With this approach, however, you'll have to make sure to print the trailing `1` after the `while` loop has ended, since the loop will terminate as soon as `last_number` becomes `1`, which means the loop won't have a chance to print it.

Another way of printing the sequence (with separating tabs), would be to store the sequence in a list, and then use `str.join` to create a string out of the list, where each element is separated by some string or character. Of course this requires that all elements in the list are strings to begin with - in this case I'm using `map` to convert the integers to strings:

```
result = "\t".join(map(str, [12, 6, 3, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1]))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
12  6   3   10  5   16  8   4   2   1
>>>
```

Comment: Wow, fast service! Your way works, but I should have clarified that I'm looking for something that could have come from a beginner -- we haven't even done try, assert, and so on. Is there anything that can be added to my code, more or less as is? The instructor was hinting that we should know, and it was easy. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds good -- I'll try it out! I was thinking that an answer to something like this would be easy to find online, but it was not. Many thanks.

Comment: @Flora Posteschild Sure thing. Let me know if anything needs explaining.